# Match a string from another table in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to write an Access query to retrieve data from the Index Table based on whether a string from the Index Table is contained within the Target Table: Example:

[Index and Target files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP8TJ.png)

```
INDEX
StationKey    StationID
Main          101
14            102
Broad         103

TARGET
StationName   Number
Main Street         
14th St            
Broad Ave
```

I want to take "Main" from the Index table, look for a string that contains it in the Target table, and attach the StationID field from the Index table.

I've tried this in SQL based on another StackOverflow post [Trying to join Access tables with like statement with list in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267761/trying-to-join-access-tables-with-like-statement-with-list-in-field):

```
Select [TARGET].[StationName], [INDEX].StationID,[INDEX].StationKey
FROM [TARGET]
Where Instr( [TARGET].[StationName],[INDEX].StationKey)>0;
```

Running this just asks me to enter parameter values on StationID and StationKey. I'm quite new at this and appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you link to the other stack overflow post?

Comment: This happens when Access does not recognise the field names. Are you using the query design screen?

Comment: @PeterSmith I think it is a problem with a join.

Comment: @ChipsterI think it is a missing table name in the query - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created your tables and data in Access. The resulting query was

```
SELECT TARGET.StationName, INDEX.StationID, INDEX.StationKey
FROM TARGET, [INDEX]
WHERE (((InStr([TARGET].[StationName],[INDEX].[StationKey]))>0));
```

This produced the correct results. The multiple brackets can be removed (carefully) for ease of reading - they are put there by Access. My result set was:

```
StationName  StationID  StationKey
Main Street  101        Main
14th St      102        4
Broad Ave    103        Broad
```

Comment: This solved it! Now I have a new problem (some StationKeys match multiple StationNames) but I think I can figure that out...

Comment: Excellent. Of course, the important aspect of a `key` is that it is unique; good luck.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Target and Index are 2 separate tables. Thus, you need a `foreign key` in one of them tell the db how the 2 tables relate to each other.

So, for instance you could change the tables to something like:

```
INDEX
StationKey    StationID
Main          101
14            102
Broad         103

TARGET
StationName   Number StationID
Main Street          101
14th St              102
Broad Ave            103
```

Doing this will create a common column that shows how the 2 tables relate to each other.

Then, you can use a [join](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6) on the StationID column in your query, and get a result of the following:

```
Joined Table on StationID
StationName   Number StationKey
Main Street          Main
14th St              14
Broad Ave            Broad
```